# Shortest path for multiple rays

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Suppose I have a transmitter (Tx) in green and a receiver (Rx) in red displayed as in the picture where the known constants are:

- $a$: height of the Tx
- $b$: height of the Rx
- $d$: distance between Tx and Rx

Then there are illustrated 2 possible ray paths from Tx to Rx. Each ray path has 2 components: the direct ray $r_1$ and the reflected ray $r_2$ so a ray path $p$ would be: $p = r_1 + r_2$.

My question is simple, yet I have not figured out yet how to solve it. What is the reflected point $x$ for which the ray path is the shortest? In other words I want to calculate what would be the shortest ray path and for that I would need to know which reflection point $x$ is the one that makes the shortest ray path.

Hope you can help me! Regards

[image]

Comment: **HINT** Consider a copy for the red point mirrored with respect to the $x$ axis (i.e. with coordinates $(d,-b)$) and then find the shortest path from the green point to this copy.

Comment: This is just the heron's problem..

Comment: @Buraian This [one](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/HeronsProblem.shtml#:~:text=Heron%27s%20problem%20has%20applications%20to%20curved%20surfaces%2C%20ellipse,Yamagata%20prefecture%20%5B%20Fukagawa%20and%20Pedoe%2C%20problem%204.1.1%5D.) is nice

Comment: Thank you @user, I was trying to solve the problem moving the reflection point in $x \in [0,d]$ but the equations got very entangled... I knew that I was missing some simple trick. Also, I am sorry for the duplicated question, it is very hard to find the equivalent problem without knowing its name

Comment: @JVGD Of course we can also proceed analytically but the trick is very effective in this case. You are welcome! Bye